# Gacutil.exe on Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, webpart

I'm trying to deploy a Web Part Feature as part of solution. Solution being add to the store and feature being added successfully. Full trust enabled in Web.Config for bin deployment of the .DLL but Web Part not working when page viewed by a non-admin user...

So, decided to deploy to GAC but discovered that gacutil.exe is not included with the OS? The only place I can find it is in the Windows SDK with a huge download size! I know I can choose to download only certain components, but which ones should I select and are there any dependencies? Better yet, is there an easier way to get a copy of the gacutil.exe tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find that MS has bundeled lots of tools into the Windows SDK as a way of maintaining version and hotfix information for these tools. Back in the Win2k days these tools were all availible individually and it was up to a user to make sure they had the version specific to their installation. E.g. changes in a service pack may require the tools to be updated to function correctly.

Saying that, I am pretty sure you can take these tools away from the SDK (and assume the risk that it may not be the correct version). If you are worried about installing the SDK on your server, try installing it to your computer and just copying the gacutil.exe to your server.

Alternatively, you could aways build a PowerShell script to deploy your DLL to the GAC? This would be a much more stable solution, IMO.

My 2c's